# how to hide the page-title / category-title

Tags: page-title

is there a way to hide the h1 page-title / category-title which shows on most pages? However, I want to only remove it on some pages.. therefore, a solution using the 'Custom Layout Update' would be best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you try it in your local.xml file

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="category.products" />                     
        </reference> 
   </default>
<layout>

or

<layout>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="category.products" />                     
        </reference> 
   </catalog_category_view>

   <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="category.products" />                     
        </reference> 
   </catalog_product_view>
<layout>
```

Comment: this is wrong because, it will remove the entire category content section, rather than removing the title. Please have a look on the link that @Marius provided in comments for the question